# What is the Chain ID for Metamask associated with truffle develop?

Tags: truffle, metamask

I was following a tutorial but found out that it is outdated. Inputting 'truffle develop' in bash states that it started on "http://127.0.0.1:9545/." However, when I try to connect Truffle and Metamask, I get this error, "Could not fetch chain ID. Is your RPC URL correct?"

I tried configuring truffle-config.js with the code below but I still get the error.

```
  networks: {
     development: {
      host: "127.0.0.1",     // Localhost (default: none)
      port: 9545,            // Standard Ethereum port (default: none)
      network_id: "*",       // Any network (default: none)
     },
```

[image: Metamask Chain ID error]

Answer (score 0):

You have to install some old version of metamask. Donwload direclty from their github. In my case, I was able to connect once installed v 5.0.0.

Just to save people time, here is the Github link to Metamask v 5.0.0: https://github.com/MetaMask/metamask-extension/releases/tag/v5.0.0

To install the zip file on chrome

1. Download the zip file and unzip it
2. Go to "chrome://extensions" on chrome
3. Check the "Developer mode" box
4. Click "Load unpacked extension..."
5. Open the folder that we unzipped in step 1

Hope it helps...

Answer (score 0):

Remember to add the trailing forward slash (/) to the RPC URL and for the Chain ID use any digit, I used 99 and network name should be Custom RPC

Answer (score 0):

First, check port 9545 is up in your OS by `netstat -ntlp`.
if it does not show anything about 9545, please check the first line of logs in the starting truffle develop command. maybe it uses another port for that.